# Convert hexa to NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, hex

i have this string

```
NSString * str = @ "01 00 00 41 8B 00 01 00 00 40 BC 00 01 00 00 43 0D 00";
```

and  i try convert it to NSacii with  this finction

```
- (NSString *)hexToString:(NSString *)string {
    NSMutableString * newString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:string];
    unsigned value;
    while([scanner scanHexInt:&value]) {
        [newString appendFormat:@"%c",(char)(value & 0xFF)];
    }
    string = [newString copy];
    [newString release];
    return [string autorelease];
}
```

it work perfect , but the problem when i want to convert the string to hex i cant find the
 00 it mean the result are 01 41 8B 01  40 BC  01 43 0D

Comment: i know that the 00 is Null in the ASCII array , haw i can return the same value

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515360/convert-string-of-hex-to-nsstring-of-text

Comment: That series of hex values is clearly not an ASCII string. Why are you trying to convert it to ASCII?

Comment: and when i convert the result i want find the same hex value with all 00

Comment: i try to convert it to ascii and write in my pdf file because the pdf file

Comment: @Alladinian: it not Duplicate question , i use the same function but i have other question

Comment: not help not yet freind?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSString *)hexToString:(NSString *)string {
    NSMutableString * newString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSScanner *scanner = [[NSScanner alloc] initWithString:string];
    unsigned value;
    while([scanner scanHexInt:&value]) {
       if (value==0 )
        {

            [newString appendString:@"\0"];

        }
        else
        {
            [newString appendFormat:@"%c",(char)(value & 0xFF)];
        }
    }
    string = [newString copy];
    [newString release];
    return [string autorelease];
}
```