# NSData from NSString as it is

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

Hey i'm trying to get text to ASCII and then store it on a server then when i get it back i want to decode the text back to NSString

i've used the following code to test on a random app.. but in here i have NSdata as a global variable so it works fine..

Question is how do i get the value NSString i get back from the server in NSData variable so i can convert it back to the text i encoded from.

```
.h

@interface passTestViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *text;
    NSData *d;
}
```

.m

```
- (IBAction)eButton:(id)sender {
    text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",@"!",[_textField text],@"!"];

    d=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",text] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",d];

    [_label setText:text];
}

- (IBAction)dButton:(id)sender {

    NSString *dString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    dString = [dString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"!" withString:@""];
    [_label setText:dString];
}
```

i need to get it to NSData. i send it to my server thru JSON and then later when i get it back... i get it as a string.. what i need is

```
NSData *d = stringThatIGetBackFromJson;
```

so i can convert it thru

```
NSString *dString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

to get the original string entered by user.

Also the string i get from this after encode has the signs and spaces.. '<' '>' and ' '
It wouldn't go thru to the url so what i did was remove the spaces and < > thru

```
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
```

so now what i'll get back is gonna be just numbers like "40786d61646f6f2131323334216b6d646f616f"... is there anyway around this ?
to compare i'm just checking encoding the text and following the same steps and then comparing if isEqualTo, but i would like to get the text back to be able to post on the app.

Comment: I'm afraid you're hopelessly confused.  You apparently don't understand that "encoding" only applies to 8-bit data -- once a string is in an NSString it's in Unicode.  You also don't understand that if you dump (or format with `%@`) an NSData object you'll see hex, not character data.  This is true of ***any*** NSData object.  (The above hex is "@xmadoo!1234!kmdoao")

Comment: So i can just use a normal hex to string convertor to convert it back..e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421282/how-to-convert-hex-to-nsstring-in-objective-c . and is there a way that i can send as data.. ? or any other option for encryption? Thnx and sry for the late reply..

Comment: Use NSString initWithData...  You should use the same string encoding that was used to produce the data originally, but UTF8 should work in almost all cases.

Comment: (You are hopelessly confused.  If you don't have someone you can discuss this with locally, start with a *very simple* test case and slowly add more features until you figure it out.)

Comment: (And next time you tell us something "didn't work" tell us precisely what happened!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the below **three** ways to convert **NSString to NSData**

> **1**.`NSData* data = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`
>
> **2**.`NSData* data=[yourString dataUsingEncoding: [NSString defaultCStringEncoding] ];`
>
> **3**.`NSData* data = [yourString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>
>            data = [data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, [data length] - 1)];`

If the data is not **null-terminated**,

```
NSString* myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:nsDataString
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;
```

If the data is **null-terminated**

```
NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[nsDataString bytes]];
```

Comment: i need to get it to NSData. i send it to my server thru JSON and then later when i get it back... i get it as a string.. what i need is 
    NSData *d = stringThatIGetBackFromJson;
so i can convert it thru
    NSString *dString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
to get the original string entered by user.

Answer (score 0):

try to change `NSASCIIStringEncoding` to `NSUTF8StringEncoding`