# Converting UTF8 Hex string to regular UTF8 encoded NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, utf-8, nsstring

I am getting UTF-8 (hex): Hc3b8rt back from a server instead of the string "Hørt".
I need to convert this response to regular UTF-8.

What I have tried:

```
NSString *string = [dict objectForKey:@"suggest"];

const char *cfilename=[string UTF8String];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cfilename];
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: If that's what you're really getting back, how would you tell if `abba` was a pop group or two hex characters?

Comment: The string you're receiving from the server is "Hc3b8rt" or "H\xC3\xB8rt" ?

Answer (score 1):

use string encoding, `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`

```
 - (id)initWithCString:(const char *)nullTerminatedCString 
              encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

Or shortly,

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCString:cfilename 
                                   encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

Edit after comments:

This is kind of strange. I have done some experiments after your comments and found some strange behaviour.

```
- (void) testStringEncodingOK {
    NSString *string = @"h\u00c3\u00a5r";
    const char *cfilename=[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    NSString *cs = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cfilename];
    NSLog(@"String: %@", cs);
}
```

This output: hår

But if you get the \U in capital, not \u, then I replaced them to \u. And then it did not work. Seem the ,

```
- (void) testStringEncodingConfused {
    NSString *string = @"h\\U00c3\\U00a5r";
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\U" withString:@"\\u"];
NSLog(@"Original string:%@", string); // now string = @"h\u00c3\u00a5r"
    const char *cfilename=[string cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
    NSString *cs = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cfilename];
    NSLog(@"String: %@", cs);
}
```

The output is, h\u00c3\u00a5r

Comment: hmmm. you server is sending Hc3b8rt not "H\xC3\xB8rt", then its a bit complicated. The server should send encoded string, I guess.

Comment: It actually sends h\U00c3\U00a5r as well. Should be "hår".

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can decode this. As @JoachimIsaksson stated in the comments above, how can you tell if "abba" is exactly "abba" or two unicode chars?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code..

```
  const char *ch = [yourstring cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

  yourstring = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:ch encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   NSLog(@"%@",yourstring);
```

let me know it is working or not...

Happy Coding....

Comment: check this answer...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421282/how-to-convert-hex-to-nsstring-in-objective-c....tell me working or not!!!!

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
NSString *string = [dict objectForKey:@"suggest"];

const char *cfilename=[string stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:cfilename];
```

and tell if it is working or not.