# card swipe status and identification information

Tags: ios, objective-c

How I can get card swipe status and identification information from card data when card is swiped.

I'm using Velocity Card Reader and want to integrate Velocity payment SDK.

For Authorize(P2PE) APIs of Velocity Required Following parameters

1. KSN
2. Encrypted Track2 data
3. Swipe status
4. Identification Information

I know how to get KSN and track2 data but don't known how to get remaining two parameters.

Example hex card data :

```
02ee00801f4221008383252a343239332a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a323532355e56414c5545442043555354
4f4d4552202020202020202020202f5e323530322a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a3f2a3b343239
332a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a323532353d323530322a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a2a3f2a913dc86ebf7541cc5c7518
8613f1e859c5204c3c4944a58b7e14bd1d323d415d00417a06ee63b64fe8e16e449057fb23be8fa9
e7baea4039d2944ea42b6fcf219ba0516af3005f9629adc5255602968e93b4360e1311cc76f66865
d6b4dfe1dd211573ad801d494efb7345af93138fdd35323554383939373939789001000000004000
f403d903
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's hex-encoded data. Using an [online conversion tool](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm), you can see the raw data is:

```
îB!%*4293********2525^VALUED CUSTOMER          /^2502**************?
*;4293********2525=2502*********?*=Èn¿uAÌ\uñèYÅ L<ID¥~½2=A]Azîc¶Oèán
DWû#¾©çºê@9ÒN¤+oÏ! Qjó_)­Å%V´6ÌvöheÖ´ßáÝ!s­INûsE¯Ý525T899799x@ôÙ
```

Really though, you'd need to refer to the documentation for whatever you're using to swipe the card. It *looks* like it's fixed-width data given the large amount of whitespace after `VALUED CUSTOMER`, but that's a complete guess on my part.

If you want to parse this string from hex into the readable (ish) string above, there's [a relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421282/how-to-convert-hex-to-nsstring-in-objective-c) here on Stack Overflow.