# Converting Hex String to ASCII String showing wrong result for 00

Tags: ios, objective-c

below is my method for Hex to ASCII conversion

```
-(NSString*)getASCIIString:(NSString*)strHex
{
    NSMutableString *strAscii = [NSMutableString string];
    for (int i=0;i<24;i+=2) {
        NSString *charValue = [strHex substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i,2)];
        unsigned int _byte;
        [[NSScanner scannerWithString:charValue] scanHexInt: &_byte];
        if (_byte >= 32 && _byte < 127) {
            [strAscii appendFormat:@"%c", _byte];
        } else {
            [strAscii appendFormat:@"[%d]", _byte];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"Hex: %@", strHex);
    NSLog(@"Ascii: %@", strAscii);
    return strAscii;
}
```

Above methode convert Hex String to ASCII but i notice for one scenario giving me wrong result as below:

strHex : 4E4932313533000000000066
Ascii  : NI2153[0][0][0][0][0]f    (Wrong)

why for 00 i am getting [0]. ?

my method work perfectly fine , only when there is 00 in Hex string as i mentioned i am getting [0] in Ascii string.

Please Let me know tested perfect conversion method.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421282/how-to-convert-hex-to-nsstring-in-objective-c) is what you looking for?

Comment: no my method work perfectly fine , only when there is 00 in Hex string as i mentioned i am getting [0] in Ascii string. it should not be ....

Comment: According to your code the output is correct since a zero byte (hex `0x0)` is a non-printable character and not in the range 32 .. 127. Don't mix it up with the *letter* 0 which is hex `0x30`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the hex string is `00`, you get the value `0` in `_byte`, and thus you are in the else branch, and get `[0]` as result for `[strAscii appendFormat:@"[%d]", _byte];`.

Comment: yes i know but is that correct way....i wanted solution...if any one has handle this condition....

Comment: What is your required result?

Comment: i really don't know ...i need standard way...just now i checked on google ...00 meaning NUL... is that correct way to handle .. i am missing some thing...

Comment: Perhaps, you could add a branch `else if(_byte == 0) { [strASCII appendString:@"NUL"]; }` in front of the else branch.